# Speed up git add for binary files - disable compression

Tags: git, compression, zarr

I am working on a new data structure that is version friendly.
So I have a git repository inside a Zarr file.
I don't have any push or upload data. just local version control.

currently, the `git add .` command is taking a lot of time.
and `git lfs` is not the right solution to the problem because the data size replicates a lot.
The question: How to disable compression for `git add .`
then I can do it using `git gc`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`git config core.compression 0`. Though I would recommend `git config core.compression 1` instead. It will be very fast, and still give decent compression.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. So I use 'git config core.compression 0' to speed up commit. 
Then, every while, I compress it with 'git gc'